# Comma before a moved verb

Tags: grammar, verbs, syntactic-analysis, commas

I can't seem to find a definitive answer for this, and my colleague and I are disagreeing on it:

> Your next obsession, found.

> Your next obsession found.

It was an advertisement, as in something like "we found your next obsession: this product."

To me, the statement without the comma reads as an incomplete one: your next obsession found *what*? It changes the subject-verb agreement entirely. However, if the comma isn't necessary but just suggested for clarity, what does the sentence without the comma mean if not just an incomplete thought?

Thanks

Comment: Grammar is about speaking not writing.

Comment: Neither is a sentence. But sentence fragments that can be clearly understood aren't wrong in certain contexts; they just don't conform to sentential grammar. That said, I'd say the variant with the comma better reflects speech patterns.

Comment: The comma replaces the missing words: Your next obsession [is hereby] found.

Comment: Compare _Paradise Lost_.

Comment: Without the comma it seems like *found* has the subject "your next obsession" and should have an object like "Your next obsession found your address". Having said that, it depends on the use; it reads like a slogan and if used as an advertising slogan on a poster, the comma might be considered ugly.

Comment: @StuartF yes—it was definitely more of a slogan-y, slang-y usage. I think it was on a coffee brand or something...as in "we found your next obsession: this coffee." Perhaps that tidbit should be included in the original post for clarity. But I do agree with you that without the comma, "your next obsession" becomes the subject of the statement rather than the direct object of what is "found" (and that "found," in this case, has an implied we/you subject).

Comment: This all depends on a wider context. These sentences don't float around in the aether. So without it. this kind of question is a fool's errand.

Comment: @Lambie what other context are you looking for? Happy to provide it, though I don't have much more than what I included here: it was on an ad, it was short-form slogan-type copy over a product meaning "we've found your next obsession: this product," and they used the version without the comma.

Comment: Widget: Your next obsession found. A slogan.

Answer (score 0):

The expression is not a sentence, obviously.  It is a slogan.  There are no rules for slogans, partly because (perhaps fortunately) they have not been studied by grammarians (or logicians).  They could be so studied, but I hope will not be.

It is fairly obvious that the slogan in question could be classified as a kind of **promise** or, perhaps, **offer**.

Two of the most important requirements of a slogan are brevity and clarity, and the O.P. slogan fully meets both. The full sentence mightbe something like

> If you are desperately looking for an (exceptional?/ fashionable?) article of fashion, design or furniture ... come in here and we can find it for you."

In fact, the slogan is vaguer than than and that has teh merit of 'inclusiveness'.  It suggests that the people inside are brilliant at finding desirable or desired 'stuff'. The slogan casts the net as widely as possible.

But what about the comma? It serves no purpose.  The normal purpose of a comma is to mark a small pause between conjoined clauses or phrases, as much to guide the rhythm of reading as the meaning.

The comma between *obsessions* and *found* has no such function.  Well, perhaps the writer wants to make the reader pause and make of the "found" a climax (or more of a climax).  But the advantage of slogans is that the standard norms applied to sentencesdo not apply.  If it is a climax you want you could, for example use three dots:

> Your next obsession ... found

Answer (score -1):

You could also argue that both are incorrect and should read "Your next obsession- found." or "Your next obsession: found.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).